# Chatter Groups for Community Users(Customer Portal)

Tags: community, chatter, customer-community, chatter-groups

I have enabled & created Community User for my Org. Now I am trying to add those community users into the Chatter group in my Org, But I am unable to add those community User.

Is there something which I need to enable to get community users into chatter groups(internal users + community users private group)

Comment: Where are you creating your chatter group? in community or internally.

Comment: Chatter Group - Internally

Comment: You cannot share a chatter group between community and internal users it seems - please upvote this idea for it https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwkzAAA

Answer (score 2):

You need to create these group in community>first login into community as sys admin . then in chatter tab try to create groups for your community user and add them . It will solve the problem.

Comment: If I try to add members, only internal users are available and not community users.

Comment: You can only add the community members while in the group via the community.